# 'Ghost' inbox message

Tags: support, comments, inbox

I just got this message in my inbox that there had been a comment that I should be aware of.

[image: comment]

When I click on it, it leads me to the [right question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128757/contacts-have-unsolicited-entries), but there is no comment there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment has been deleted after your message was sent and before you got a chance to check it out.  The system isn't clever enough to recall or cancel the message, so it sends you to where is was, even if it's gone.

I've deleted your subsequent reply as is is now out of context.

Comment: I was suspecting that, just wondering what the <br/> was in it ?

Comment: probably someone trying to insert a newline into a comment, as it's not possible.

Comment: while we are on the topic, is there a way to inform me when my comment is deleted ?? I know I made a comment to that question but it is no longer there?

Comment: No idea, might be worth a separate meta question on SO

Comment: OK, just clarifying it was not one of the moderators, since obviously you can do that :(